# Loop through an object and return the values of a specific property

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am trying to loop through an object and get the specific properties values, but I am only either getting the keys or the values. Here is what I am doing:

```
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" }
     ],
}

for (key in fakeData) {
 console.log(`${key}:${fakeData[key]}`)
}
```

I am trying to get the title of the cars property. I have tried doing `${key.cars}:${fakeData[key.cars]}` but I get undefined. Any suggestions how to access that property? TIA

Comment: I cannot understand what is that you exactly want. can you also mention the output what you are expecting

Comment: either you need to loop over cars/used cars directly, or you need multiple or nested loops.

Comment: I am expecting the output to be CALI, TEXAS, NY

Comment: @KevinB that would be an overkill

Comment: @boomchickawawa i mean, it's what the accepted answer does. :shrug:

Comment: @KevinB look closely, those are two different approaches

Comment: @boomchickawawa both using map and looping are loops, and in the case of that answer, they're looping over cars directly. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" },
     ],
}

// using map
let carTitles = fakeData.cars.map(({title})=>title);

console.log(carTitles);

// using for loop

let carTitles2=[];
for ({title} of fakeData.cars)
  carTitles2.push(title);

console.log(carTitles2);
console.log('cars as string are:', carTitles2.join(','));

// both cars and usedCars using one loop
let cs  = '';
let ucs = '';
let clen=fakeData.cars.length;
let uclen=fakeData.usedCars.length;
let len=Math.max(clen,uclen);
for (let i=0;i<len;i++) {
   if (clen>0 && i<clen)
     cs = cs + (i ? ',' : '') + fakeData.cars[i].title;
   if (uclen>0 && i<uclen)
     ucs = ucs + (i ? ',' : '') + fakeData.usedCars[i].title;
}

console.log('cars are:', cs);
console.log('used cars are:', ucs);
```

Comment: love this, thanks that makes perfect sense!

Comment: This works great! I am trying to get all the titles in a single statement. Something like "The new cars are in CALI, TEXAS, NY" but when I do it I get the output in multi line statements like "The new cars are in CALI" "The new cars are in TEXAS" "The new cars are in NY". Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I am trying to get both the `cars` and `usedCars` in one statement like `'All cars are :CALI, TEXAS, NY, FL' `and I am doing it using two for loops one is the same as above and the other loop is for the `fakeData.usedCars` and pushing that to `carTitles2`. It works as expected but was wondering if there is a better way that would not use two for loops

Comment: Yes it is possible in one loop but its rare. I did update the answer. Also it's possible using ```Array.reduce``` instead of traditional for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through cars object and logs the car titles.

```js
var fakeData = {
     "manufacturer": "tesla",
     "cars": [
          {"title": "CALI", "name": "CALI", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "TEXAS", "name": "TEXAS", "type": "string" },
          {"title": "NY", "name": "NY", "type": "string" }
     ],
     "usedCars": [
          {"title": "FL", "name": "FL", "type": "string" }
     ],
}

let result = ''

for (car of fakeData.cars) {  
  result += `The new cars are in ${car.title}\n`;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works great! I am trying to get all the titles in a single statement. Something like "The new cars are in CALI, TEXAS, NY" but when I do it I get the output in multi line statements like "The new cars are in CALI" "The new cars are in TEXAS" "The new cars are in NY". Any idea how to do this?

Comment: i updated the snippet. you can try it now

Comment: I am trying to get both the cars and usedCars in one statement like 'All cars are :CALI, TEXAS, NY, FL' and I am doing it using two for loops one is the same as above and the other loop is for the fakeData.usedCars and pushing that to carTitles2. It works as expected but was wondering if there is a better way that would not use two for loops